# Can't connect to my Elasticsearch instance: NoNodeAvailableException

Tags: java, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, elasticsearch-5

Can't connect to my Elasticsearch started with:

```
docker-compose up
```

Running command:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_nodes/http?pretty
```

Output:

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "nodes" : {
    "qD18rHzhQaexExUw5sBgXg" : {
      "name" : "Scanner",
      "transport_address" : "172.19.0.3:9300",
      "host" : "172.19.0.3",
      "ip" : "172.19.0.3",
      "version" : "6.2.3",
      "build" : "fcbb46d",
      "http_address" : "172.19.0.3:9200",
      "http" : {
        "bound_address" : [ "0.0.0.0:9200" ],
        "publish_address" : "172.19.0.3:9200",
        "max_content_length_in_bytes" : 104857600
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Connect with transport client:

```
public Client client() throws Exception {
    Settings settings = Settings.builder()
        .put("spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes", "localhost:9300")
        .build();

    TransportClient client = TransportClient.builder()
        .settings(settings)
        .build()
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
    return client;
}
```

Get error:

```
Caused by: NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}]]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:326)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:223)
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch
    ports:
      - '9200:9200'
      - '9300:9300'
  kibana:
    image: kibana
    ports:
      - '5601:5601'
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM elasticsearch, kibana
EXPOSE 9200
EXPOSE 9300
```

(running a local installed Elasticsearch *without* Docker it works!)

What am I doing wrong? Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Make sure that the version of your elastic client matches your elastic version!! That was my issue. Still got NoNodeAvailableException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When downgrading to elasticsearch:2.4.4 it works, I suspect it has to do with SpringData not being compatible with latest Elasticsearch.

```
   ...
    services:
      elasticsearch:
        image: elasticsearch:2.4.4
        ports:
          - '9200:9200'
          - '9300:9300'
      kibana:
        image: kibana:4.6.1
    ...
```

Charts:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch

https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix

Comment: No, that's because "Note: since 5.0, Elasticsearch only listens on localhost by default on both http and transport endpoints)" - https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch/

Comment: Could you clarify, I made the changes you suggested on the newer version of Elasticsearch but it did not work. So I removed everything and installed 2.4.4 and it works. I looked on the compatible chart for SpringData and it only supports older versions of Elasticsearch.

Comment: Make sure that the version of your elastic client matches your elastic version!! That was my issue. Still got `NoNodeAvailableException`.

Answer (score 0):

Transport endpoint is bound on localhost inside `elasticsearch` container. That's why it is only accessible from the container itself.

Transport endpoint should be bound to `0.0.0.0` (`"transport_address" : "0.0.0.0:9300"`) in `elasticsearch` container and it will be possible to access it via localhost on a host machine by `localhost:9300`.

So, you can achieve that with the following `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch
    command: "-Etransport.host=0.0.0.0"
    ports:
      - '9200:9200'
      - '9300:9300'
  kibana:
    image: kibana
    ports:
      - '5601:5601'
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
```

**Update:**

If you just use the above `docker-compose.yaml`, `elasticsearch` container fails with the following error when it starts:

```
elasticsearch_1  | [2018-03-26T07:44:13,475][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [rzYPgrJ] starting ...
elasticsearch_1  | [2018-03-26T07:44:13,663][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [rzYPgrJ] publish_address {172.17.0.2:9300}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9300}
elasticsearch_1  | [2018-03-26T07:44:13,688][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [rzYPgrJ] bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks
elasticsearch_1  | ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed
elasticsearch_1  | [1]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
elasticsearch_1  | [2018-03-26T07:44:13,696][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [rzYPgrJ] stopping ...
elasticsearch_1  | [2018-03-26T07:44:13,747][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [rzYPgrJ] stopped
elasticsearch_1  | [2018-03-26T07:44:13,747][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [rzYPgrJ] closing ...
elasticsearch_1  | [2018-03-26T07:44:13,762][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [rzYPgrJ] closed
```

That's because we changed `transport endpoint` be listened on `0.0.0.0`.

In order to fix it, it is necessary to increase `vm.max_map_count` sysctl parameter on a host mashine at least up to `262144`:

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Now you can successfully start both containers by `docker-compose up`.

Comment: Thanks for answer Im not sure though, should I edit the Docker container elasticsearch.yml, the docker-compose.yml or my Java client() method above and with what settings?

Comment: @powder366 added additional info to the answer.

Comment: Thank for feedback, now I cant issue the curl command above, get curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused. And I get the same message NoNodeAvailableException when trying to connect. Also get  the following from console output from Docker: kibana_1         | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-03-26T07:45:38Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch"],"pid":12,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
kibana_1         | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-03-26T07:45:38Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch"],"pid":12,"message":"No living connections"}

Comment: @powder366 added additional info to the answer

Comment: I did not get a problem with my max_map_count, but have the problem according to my previous comment, after your suggested change.

Comment: Downgraded to elasticsearch:2.4.4 and it started working.